# Comparar registros entre duas tabelas no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Preciso de uma solução que compare quaisquer alterações sofridas na tabela ***produtos_csv*** em relação a tabela ***produtos*** mesmo que seja apenas a troca de uma (*letra ou número*) em algum campo.

Estou usando o código abaixo mas só funciona para registros únicos pois se houver registros duplicados em um *loop* não atende.

```
 $sql= "SELECT * FROM produtos_csv 
                WHERE produto_codigo NOT IN (SELECT produto_codigo FROM produtos)
                OR produto_descricao NOT IN (SELECT produto_descricao FROM produtos)";
```

Exemplo de alteração de Registro:

TABELA produtos_csv chegou com campo `produto_descricao='Bolas Azuis'`
e na TABELA produtos está com o campo produto_descricao='Bola Azul'

Comment: Coloca um exemplo dos registros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As duas tabelas tem alguma coisa em comum para referenciar entre si? por exemplo uma `PK`? Aí basta fazer um `join` e comparar os campos. poderia ser algo do tipo.

```
SELECT
    p1.*,
    p2.*
FROM produtos_csv p1
INNER JOIN produtos p2
ON p2.codigo = p1.codigo -- DIGAMOS QUE ISSO SEJA SUA PK
WHERE p1.produto_descricao != p2.produto_descricao
OR p1.produto_codigo_barra != p2.produto_codigo_barra
OR ... -- E vai adicionando as comparações necessárias
```

Isso irá resultar os produtos que estão diferentes entre elas.

Comment: Sim, tinha PK deu certo obrigado !

Comment: Boa!! por nada! =)